# Маштабирование QLabel в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как сделать так, чтобы `QLabel` менял размеры, когда я введу больше чем один символ.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
    QInputDialog, QApplication, QLabel)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Input dialog')

        self.btn = QPushButton('Dialog', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 20)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        self.le = QLabel(self)
        self.le.move(130, 22)

    def showDialog(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')

        if ok:
            self.le.setText(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = Example()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ваше приложение подстраивалось под размеры вводимых значений и верно масштабировалось, лучше всего использовать менеджеры компоновки, например `QHBoxLayout`. Менеджеры компоновки также избавят вас от ручной установки элементов.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QInputDialog, QApplication, QHBoxLayout
import sys


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Dialog')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.le = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.le)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Input dialog')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')
        if ok:
            self.le.setText(str(text))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `label.adjustSize()`